# Is it possible to clone an existing Visual Flow?

Tags: flow

Is it possible to clone an existing Visual Flow ?

Answer (score 7):

When you try to "Save As" on an active flow then you can select to save a "New Version" or a "New Flow". The New Flow would be your new copy of existing flow.